# Error when getting state value: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys

Tags: reactjs, api, react-chartjs

I'm super new to react and sorry for asking such this simple question.

I'm trying to create a chart using ChartJS from an online API.

My js script:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        daily_data: [],
        hourly_data: [],
        currency: this.props.currency,
        chartData: {}
    }
    this.getChartData = this.getChartData.bind(this);

}

getChartData() {

    this.setState({
        chartData: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: Object.keys(this.state.daily_data[this.state.currency]),
                    data: Object.values(this.state.daily_data[this.state.currency]),
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                }
            ]
        }
    })

}

 componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://asia-northeast1-s3688090-cc2018.cloudfunctions.net/cool-api")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({
        daily_data: result,
    }))
    .catch(error => console.log("error" + error));
      }


render() {
    this.getChartData();
    return (
   ....
    )
 }
```

The problem occurs at: `label: Object.keys(this.state.daily_data[this.state.currency])`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
at ViewDetails.getChartData (bundle.js:82729)
at ViewDetails.render (bundle.js:82783)
at bundle.js:55899
at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:55180)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (bundle.js:55898)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (bundle.js:55925)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:55467)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:55363)
at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:8034)
```

The fetch API is working fine as in my react tool it actually shows that state `daily_data` has all the API value:

[image]

As I've read the documents as well as some similar questions on StackOverflow states that ReactJS doesn't mutate the update immediately and can call callback to solve the problem I'm not sure if it's really the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try use Async Await
- And change **`componentWillMount()`** with **`componentDidMount()`**

  `async componentDidlMount() {
      const response = await fetch("https://asia-northeast1-s3688090-cc2018.cloudfunctions.net/cool-api");
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({ daily_data: json });
  }`

Comment: if you try use dummy currency on state, still error ? `currency: "AUD"`

Comment: yes, tried hard coding: `Object.keys(this.state.daily_data["AUD"])` still invokes the same error. I think the problem is at the moment when i call `this.state.daily_data` it's still null.

Comment: console.log(this.state.daily_data) at getChartData() returns array length 0.

Comment: Ohh, after adding this.getChartData() to async componentDidMount() it works !!! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider giving your `label` key an initial value, perhaps an empty array.

Comment: Hi, tried hard coding label values but it shows the same error. in the data field.

Comment: You should also remove your `getChartData()` method from the render method. You can invoke it in componentDidUpdate() instead, only if the `dailyData` state changes.

Comment: I think it's because setState() hasn't updated yet but i called `this.state.daily_data[this.state.currency]` already